# Why won't the program include the first input from the user in the calculation of the average?

Tags: java, if-statement, do-while

This code is meant to output an average of -1 if the first value entered by the user is -1. If the value entered is not -1, then it will calculate the average of the given values, and it will stop when the value -1 is entered and it will be the stopping signal for the program. The task is to modify an existing DoWhile loop - which I have done.

Now, after having written the code, I can't seem to understand why the program isn't including the first input from the user, for the calculation of the average.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

float grade;
float sumGrades, average;
int studentCount = 0;
sumGrades = 0;

final int STOP = -1;

System.out.printf("\nEnter a grade (%d to finish): ", STOP);
grade = input.nextFloat();
if(grade == STOP)
{
      sumGrades = sumGrades + grade;
      studentCount++;
}
else
    do
    {
    System.out.printf("\nEnter a grade (%d to finish): ", STOP);
    grade = input.nextFloat();

    if(grade != STOP)
      {
      sumGrades = sumGrades + grade;
      studentCount++;
      }
    } while(grade != STOP);

average = sumGrades / studentCount;
System.out.printf("The average obtained is %.1f\n", average);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter a grade (-1 to finish): 2

Enter a grade (-1 to finish): 3

Enter a grade (-1 to finish): 4

Enter a grade (-1 to finish): 5

Enter a grade (-1 to finish): 2

Enter a grade (-1 to finish): 3

Enter a grade (-1 to finish): -1

The average obtained is 3.4
```

OUTPUT 2:

```
Enter a grade (-1 to finish): 2

Enter a grade (-1 to finish): -1

The average obtained is NaN
```

[Image of Compiled Code and Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcYRs.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLvcK.png)

Comment: Please do not add images, instead copy your code. If it's too long then you should reduce it to a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: before formatting `average` as `%.1f`, please debug and see what value average has.

Comment: `if(grade == STOP)` You are only adding the first number if it is equal to the `STOP`. Why are you asking for a grade before the `do while` anyway?

Comment: Even if the average isn't formatted as     %.1f , it still outputs the wrong average.

Comment: The code must output an average of -1, if the first input is -1. That is why the first if statement is added. Without the first if statement, once it enters the dowhile it will output     The average obtained is NaN, if the value -1 is entered.

Comment: @KPC2 Yes but if the first input is NOT -1, you are not doing anything with it.

Comment: If the first input is not -1, then it will enter the do while, and the code will stop once -1 is entered. Then yes the first if statement is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main issiue is here:

```
   final int STOP = -1;


        System.out.printf("\nEnter a grade (%d to finish): ", STOP);
      grade = input.nextFloat(); 
if(grade == STOP)
{
      sumGrades = sumGrades + grade;
      studentCount++;
}
```

here you read input, and just check if its STOP, bud you do nothing with input if isnt STOP
in next

```
else
    do
    {
    System.out.printf("\nEnter a grade (%d to finish): ", STOP);
    grade = input.nextFloat();
```

you again read input and then process it if isnt STOP and you lose your first input

solution by one cycle:

```
do
    {
    System.out.printf("\nEnter a grade (%d to finish): ", STOP);
    grade = input.nextFloat();
        if(grade != STOP)
          {
            sumGrades = sumGrades + grade;
            studentCount++;
          }

      } while(grade != STOP);
```

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you. Do you have any possible suggestions in fixing the code, so that it doesn't lose the first input, but still output -1 if it is the first input?

Comment: easy fix is to move the second  `grade = input.nextFloat();` just before `} while(grade != STOP);`

Comment: there is ofcourse other solution for it :) you can do it only in one cycle do {}until

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at what you have written.

```
System.out.printf("\nEnter a grade (%d to finish): ", STOP);
grade = input.nextFloat();
```

OK so far

```
if(grade == STOP)
{
      sumGrades = sumGrades + grade;
      studentCount++;
}
```

So ... if the grade means "stop" ... you add it to the sum, and count?!?

```
else
    do
    {
```

But if the previous grade was NOT a stop ... you throw it away and read the next grade!?!

```
    System.out.printf("\nEnter a grade (%d to finish): ", STOP);
    grade = input.nextFloat();
```

See the problem?

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you. Okay, I understand. Thank you. Do you have any possible suggestions in fixing the code, so that it doesn't lose the first input, but still output -1 if it is the first input?